# How do you log URL's of 404 page not found?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I've search but haven't found....

I recently created a new layout for a website. It is live now. Traffic seems to be going down. I am afraid that I forgot to move some of the pages over. Is there any way to log url's that people go to but doesn't exist?

For example:
If Joe goes to www.sample.com/page3
and if that page doesn't exist, I want it to log the url in say error.log on the server

Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: are you handling 404 yourself? you can always use google webmaster tools to see what are the 404 on your site. but it will be much better if you handle it internally

Comment: Apache already logs these in the access log, just look for lines with a 404 status. This is normally the 5th field, try `grep '" 404 [0-9]' access_log` to grab them.

Comment: You can also install a stat suite such as webalizer or awstats that will show you the 404s people are hitting, and how many times it's been hit.

Comment: Or you can design your application with a front controller to route requests. That way you'll always know when a request results in a 404 and you can log those events yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys, i think I will go with the first plan - which is google webmasters.